# Error querying the https webpage

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest, webclient, unauthorized

I'm trying to download the webpage from a https web page. When I try this using browser it works, but it doesn't work in C#. Tried both webclient and WebRequest. Same error "UnAuthorized". Any help is appreciated. Tried looking at other solutions like saving cookies using WebRequest. But didn't worked.

I was able to retrieve the headers from the response. The authentication type is NTLM and in browser I see a dialog box with username and password. Tried this in our test server. it works fine. But doesn't work with this webpage.

Headers = {Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate,NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 20:02:07 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_legacy_www=1269436588.20480.0000; path=/
}

Using webClient

```
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = null;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, policy) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
                string data = client.DownloadString(url);
                return data;
            }
```

using WebRequest

```
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, policy) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the URL. When I was doing in browser, it was redirecting to the correct URL. Fiddler logs helped. Added code to handle the http redirection logic.